# What's the most pythonic way to apply a function on every word in a string with multiple types of white space characters?

Tags: python, string, whitespace

Suppose I have a function

```
def f(a):
  return a[::-1]
```

I want to apply the function f to every word on a string. If the string consists only of spaces, I can do

```
>>> s = '   this  is a banana   '
>>> ' '.join(map(f, s.split(' ')))
'   siht  si a ananab   '
```

But how can I do this when the string consists of multiple types of white spaces? (e.g., \t and \n)

For example, I want to change

```
'\t  \t this  is a\tbanana   \n'
```

to

```
'\t  \t siht  si a\tananab   \n'
```

Comment: And, you also want to preserve what you split by at joining?

Comment: @AKS yes, I want to preserve the types of white spaces

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a regular expression, the [`re.sub()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) accepts a function to do the substitutions. Match *non-whitespace* instead:

```
re.sub(r'[^\s]+', lambda m: f(m.group(0)), s)
```

The function is passed a [match object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects); using `.group(0)` you can extract the matched text to pass it to your function. The return value is used to replace the original matched text in the output string.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> def f(a):
...   return a[::-1]
...
>>> s = '\t  \t this  is a\tbanana   \n'
>>> re.sub(r'[^\s]+', lambda m: f(m.group(0)), s)
'\t  \t siht  si a\tananab   \n'
```

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions, where you can easily get whole words and also whole chunks of continuous whitespace.

Comment: You can do this even if the function if is complex? (e.g, result of database access)

Comment: Yeah, basically you want to use `re.split('\s*', your_text)` to get only the whitespace, or something like that.

Comment: @irvan, `re.sub` takes a callable second argument so the approach can work.